# Why is my PhoneGap app appears corrupted on load?

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, osx-lion

I have created a project based on PhoneGap 2.6.0. I haven't made any changes to it. When I try to run it in 4.2.2 emulator the visual is corrupted or I am not sure how to put it.

**Screenshot of how the PhoneGap 2.6.0 app looks like in 4.2.2**
[image: Screenshot of how the PhoneGap 2.6.0 app looks like in 4.2.2]

If I resume the app after pausing it, by pressing the Back key and re-launching the app, then it opens up fine.

**The app looks fine when relaunched after pausing it**
[image: The app looks fine when relaunched after pausing it]

Googling leads me to `deviceready` event not fired issue. I am not sure if that is linked to it, but anyway that seems to have been fixed in 2.3.0.

**Points to note:**

- This works fine in 2.3.3 emulator.
- I am running the latest Android SDK.
- I have OSX Lion.

Comment: Ok this seems like another emulator bug. If I disable `Use GPU` then it works fine. In fact in the above screenshot the gray patch near bottom is the actual app UI. Somehow the rest is rendered black, hence the visual corruption.

Comment: That's a really strange emulator bug!

Comment: I'd like to suggest you answer your own question - your comment "Ok this seems like another emulator bug. If I disable Use GPU then it works fine. In fact in the above screenshot the gray patch near bottom is the actual app UI" is the answer, and it helped me greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with how the timers are executed.
You may need to throw in your onCreate method after you load the url:

```
super.appView.resumeTimers();
```

So now the code looks like this:

```
super.loadUrl(url, 10000);        
super.appView.resumeTimers();
```